# Placing PHP within Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I can't seem to get the PHP to echo out within a Javascript tag:

```
places.push(new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo the_field('lat', 1878); ?>"));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the function (`the_field('lat', 1878)`) work correctly?

Comment: is the file extension of your page php?

Comment: Yep, it's running through wordpress, so definitely.

Comment: Yes, when placed within normal html it echo's out fine.

Comment: Post a more complete example, or try to reproduce it on a smaller scale and post that.

Comment: Are you severing this file through PHP or not?

Comment: strange... please try something more simple like `alert('<?php echo 'test'; ?>');`

Comment: Rob, if you're going to down vote other people, at least give them a reason for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it without the quotes ?

```
places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo the_field('lat', 1878); ?>));
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP works when you execute the page, and it should work. 
Please note that php does not execute when you run a JS function.
Please also make sure that you really have that `the_field` function.

Comment: the_field exists and echo out when just within html. I just want to echo the field within the javascript, surely that's possible right?

Comment: view source in the browser to see what it output

Comment: +1 for "php does not execute when you run a JS function". I could see a new developer easily making this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have your " quotes in the LatLng method arguments when there shouldn't be any.

Your php should output a string such as '50.123123123, 12.123144' (without the ' quotes). The LatLng method expects 2 values.

```
places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo the_field('lat', 1878); ?>));
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to populate a Google Map with markers as the result of a database query, you probably want to wrap it in a JSON web service. Something as simple as:

```
<?php
// file to query database and grab palces
// do database connection
$places = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM places";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $places[] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($places);
exit;
```

And then in your JavaScript file:

```
// get places
$.getJSON('getplaces.php', function(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        place[] = response[i];
        places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(place.lat, place.lng));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand what you are trying to do (maybe some more explanation of your problem is required for this), then this might be your answer:

```
places.push(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo '"' . the_field('lat', 1878) . '"' ?>));
```

EDIT: removed the ;

Comment: That just gives me the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/medicom/public_html/mapping/wp-content/themes/default/page.php on line 43

Comment: @Rob: this was the typo by the answerer. Try removing the unnecessary `;`.